# I m unable to use List<Users> and Optional<Users> to create a function which returns all the users.in spring boot. I have used jpa repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I m unable to use List and Optional to create a function which returns the list of all users. It says list and optional is not generic type. I have created repository using jpa repository.

I m expecting list and optional both are generic

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Show your code. Read [ask], take the [tour], then [edit] your question to include a textual [mre] (*not* a screenshot!)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.